# Struts Assistant Tool Window does not come up in IntelliJ

Tags: java, struts2, intellij-idea, tiles2

I have a project with the Struts 2 framework detected successfully in IntelliJ *(12.1.6).*

However, I am not able to see the Struts Assistant Tool Window. I am looking for that and Tiles support inside IntelliJ.  The web application compiles and deploys fine but I constantly get these inspection warnings inside the IDE.

I am also unable to add more files to the feature set manually. Is there something extra to be done for the Struts assistant tool window to appear?

Also, There is no Struts Assistant Tool Window in `View|Tool Window` Menu.
Note: Have tried Invalidate Cache already.

*Attaching screenshots*:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tiles feature is only available in the Struts Facet Page, the page are you looking is Struts2 Facet Page. You can press <kbd>Help</kbd> button on this page to learn more.

Comment: Never realized that struts has better support (in terms of visual framework editing wizards) than Struts2 in IntelliJ. Thanks for pointing this out.